# strange % mark in every line of integrated terminal in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, babun

VSCode Version: 1.21.1
OS Version: Windows 7
hi all :

I am using zsh (using babun) as my terminal ( i'm using windows 7) and it's working
great but in vscode a strange "%" character appear before every line as in picture ... anybody know how to remove it?
[image]

Comment: It looks like it is either the start of your actual prompt, or it is the result of `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` being used.

Comment: So how to remove it? ... Sorry if its a noob question

Comment: in your ~/.zshrc I would add a line `export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''`, then `source ~/.zshrc`, and restart vscode.  I would also consider adding a full block - `setopt PROMPT_CR` and `setopt PROMPT_SP`, then `export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''`